# distance between two points with varying speeds

Tags: linear-algebra

A Man walked from his house to office at 5kmph and got 20 minutes late. if he had travelled at 7.5kmph, he would have reached 12 minutes early. The distance from his house to office is?

Here s1 = 5kmph t1 = t2 + 20 + 12 s2 = 7.5kmph t2 = t2 
(S1 / S2) = (t2 / t1) ------> (5/7.5) = (t2 / t2 + 32) ---------> 5t2 + 160 = 7.5t2 -------> t2 = 64 minutes 
So distance = 7.5 X 1.7 (64 mins) = 8km

i dont understand why t1=t2+20+12
what my approach was speed x time = distance
so 
x = original time ; y = distance between his office and home
5 *(x+20) = y 
        7.5 * (x-12) = y but i get a wrong answer using this
i dont understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$5(x+20)=7.5(x-12)$$
$$5x+100=7.5x-90$$
$$2.5x=190$$
$$x=76\text{ minutes}$$
But here, $x$ is the original time, which is not the same as $t_1$ or $t_2$. So,
$$\text{Distance}=7.5\times\frac{(76-12)}{60}=8 \text{ km}$$